# Angular - Scope variable updated but view isn't - ngTagInput

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm using ngTagsInput in which I have a 3 tags `one, two, three`.

When i click on remove `one` the fields shows `one, two` rather than `two, three`.

I've checked the scope variable and I can see the correct `two, three`.

So I've tried to literally clear and reinstaniate the scope variable however no luck.

Am i missing something?

HTML looks like:

```
<tags-input ng-model="detail.tagsToAddField" add-on-space="true"
                    placeholder="." on-tag-removed="detail.tagRemoved($tag)">
</tags-input>
```

and in the controller, i'm literally trying to reinstate but it makes no difference to the tags in the field.

```
self.tagRemoved = function($tag) {
    var current = $scope.detail.tagsToAddField;
    $scope.detail.tagsToAddField = [];
    $scope.detail.tagsToAddField = current;  
};
```

Anyone used this ngTagsInput?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`on-tag-removed` is used to fire a callback when you're actually done removing the tag from the input, you really should not modify or rearrange your tag list in that function except for extreme cases, because your tag was already removed from the list at that point. so "reinstating" won't do anything

Because you didn't post much of any code that is useful for fixing your issue. Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LAk3hu?p=preview) (forked from the [demos](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos)) with your use case working properly.